# Decode Unicode's to Local language in Bigquery

Tags: javascript, google-bigquery, decode

We receive a survey Web-hook data in Bigquery. The comment in local language is captured as unicode and we do have special character in that comment.

- **Example**

  - Comment in survey- "别老是晚点，现场补行李费太贵"
  - Comment in Bigquery data- "\u522b\u8001\u662f\u665a\u70b9\uff0c\u73b0\u573a\u8865\u884c\u674e\u8d39\u592a\u8d35"

We found a solution for decode individual comment :-

```
    CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION utf8convert(s STRING)
    RETURNS STRING
    LANGUAGE js AS """
    return unescape( ( s ) );
    """;
    with sample AS (SELECT '\u522b\u8001\u662f\u665a' AS S)
    SELECT utf8convert(s) from sample
```

When implement this code in comment field with thousand of comment and different languages its not working.

```
    CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION utf8convert(s STRING)
    RETURNS STRING
    LANGUAGE js AS """
    return unescape( ( s ) );
    """;
   SELECT Comment, utf8convert(Comment) as Convert
   FROM `airasia-nps.nps_production.NPSDashboard_Webhook_Data1`
   where Comment is not null
```

no error while running but the result is in Unicode does not change to local language.
[Result: local language in Unicode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SufQl.png)

- I have try this code

  ```
    CREATE TEMP FUNCTION DecodeUnicode(s STRING) AS (
    IF(s NOT LIKE '%\\u%', s,
    (SELECT CODE_POINTS_TO_STRING(ARRAY_AGG(CAST(CONCAT('0x', x) AS INT64)))
    FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(s, '\\u')) AS x
     WHERE x != ''))
    );

    SELECT
    original,
    DecodeUnicode(original) AS decoded
    FROM (
    SELECT trim(r'$-\u6599\u91d1\u304c\u9ad8\u3059\u304e\uff01\uff01\uff01') AS original UNION ALL
    SELECT trim(r'abcd')
    );
  ```

shows [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PxoH1.png) i think its because the comment start with special character?.

Comment: Can you explain why the solution you found is not working? Any way to reproduce? What's the error message?

Comment: No error while running but the result is in Unicode does not change to local language. Here with i have attach the code and result.

Comment: weird thing is that if we try decoding the characters that didn't work for you they still work normally. Just out of curiosity I wonder what would happen if you select only one row that didn't encode properly and try to decode just that to see what happens ( i tried simulating broken characters but as far as i could see it just throws exceptions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this works. It does the "manual" decoding for strings that have \u in them by converting to Unicode code points and then to a string. It should be faster than using JavaScript, too.

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION DecodeUnicode(s STRING) AS (
  IF(s NOT LIKE '%\\u%', s,
     (SELECT CODE_POINTS_TO_STRING(ARRAY_AGG(CAST(CONCAT('0x', x) AS INT64)))
      FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(s, '\\u')) AS x
      WHERE x != ''))
);

SELECT
  original,
  DecodeUnicode(original) AS decoded
FROM (
  SELECT r'\u522b\u8001\u662f\u665a\u70b9\uff0c\u73b0\u573a\u8865\u884c\u674e\u8d39\u592a\u8d35' AS original UNION ALL
  SELECT r'abcd'
);
```

As output, this returns `别老是晚点，现场补行李费太贵` and `abcd`.

Comment: its work but when the comment start with special character shows error?. 
        Query Failed
        Error: Bad int64 value: 0x$-

Comment: It sounds like you have input that doesn't follow the pattern that you described in your question.

Comment: its that i need to add regex for this case? herewith i have add the code and error in question.

Comment: Use a regex to strip off the invalid data then.

Comment: Please post a separate question instead of going back and forth in comments.

Comment: I have add a question please have a look : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47322494/regex-for-special-character-decode-unicode  thank you