# function to convert unicode in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery, unicode-normalization

I trying out the NORMALIZE function with NFKC in bigquery from the documentation, I see that I can convert a string to a readable format.  For example

```
WITH EquivalentNames AS (
  SELECT name
  FROM UNNEST([
      'Jane\u2004Doe',
      '\u0026 Hello'
      ]) AS name
)
SELECT
  NORMALIZE(name, NFKC) AS normalized_str
FROM EquivalentNames
GROUP BY 1;
```

The ampersand character shows up correctly, but I have a table, with a column of STRING with unicode character in its values, but I'm not able to use NORMALIZE to convert it to a readable format.

I've also tried some of the other solutions presented 
[Decode Unicode's to Local language in Bigquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47150140/decode-unicodes-to-local-language-in-bigquery) but nothing is working yet.

Attached is an example of the data:
[image]

Comment: Please clarify--do you mean that you have strings that look like `'Jane\\u2004Doe'`, i.e. the escape appears within the contents? The example you provided doesn't have this behavior.

Comment: attached image of data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You posted a question about `NORMALIZE`, but didn't make your goals clear.

Here I'll answer the question about `NORMALIZE` - to point out that it probably doesn't do what you are expecting it to do. But at least it's acting as expected.

There are many ways to encode the same string with Unicode. Normalize chooses one, while preserving the string.

See this query:

```
SELECT *, a=b ab, a=c ac, a=d ad, b=c bc, b=d bd, c=d cd
FROM (
  SELECT NORMALIZE('hello ñá ', NFC) a
   , NORMALIZE('hello ñá ', NFKC) b
   , NORMALIZE('hello ñá ', NFD) c
   , NORMALIZE('hello ñá ', NFKD) d
)
```

[image]

As you see - every time you get the same string, they just have different non-visible representations.

Comment: I'm trying to replace unicode character with their readable version

Comment: add examples to the question please

Comment: ok attached an image of some of the data in the table.  Currently using `REGEXP_REPLACE` to replace as a way to solve the problem.

Comment: ok, I see a picture of how it looks - now I want to know how you want it to look

Comment: Ok, on further investigation, I think this is not the way the data is in the table, I've mangled uri decoding & the unicode in another function.  So sorry...

Answer (score 1):

The `\u2004` is so called `thick space` so that is why you thnk it is not showing correctly because you just see space - 
But if you will try some other codes - like for example `\2020` - you will see it is actually showing even without extra processing with NORMALIZE function

As in below

```
#standardSQL
WITH EquivalentNames AS (
  SELECT name
  FROM UNNEST([
      'Jane\u2020Doe',
      '\u0026 Hello'
      ]) AS name
)
SELECT
  name, NORMALIZE(name, NFKC) AS normalized_str
FROM EquivalentNames
GROUP BY 1
```

with result

```
Row name        normalized_str   
1   Jane†Doe    Jane†Doe     
2   & Hello     & Hello
```