# BigQuery SQL - Fixing Broken Special Characters

Tags: javascript, google-bigquery, special-characters

Our tables have been loaded with broken special characters and I'm trying to find a way to fix through Standard SQL, temp JS function, or otherwise in BigQuery web UI.

The broken text is this:
`DÃ©cor`
but should be this: `Dècor`

I've already tried some solutions I've found on SO, including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47150140/decode-unicodes-to-local-language-in-bigquery) but none of them work.

Is there a way to fix using Standard SQL, temp JS function, or another way in BigQuery web UI?

Comment: show more examples of broken stuff

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant, this is it for now but I'm looking for a comprehensive function where all special characters passed through the function are converted correctly. I've searched quite a bit but doesn't seem like there's one that consistently works across use cases

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a lot of columns, you can just use `REPLACE(brokencolumn, 'Ã©', 'è')`.

You can still use it if you have a lot of columns, but it could be better to find an automating method doing it :)

Comment: hi sabri, this works but I'm looking for a more comprehensive solution where the error is unknown but as long as the special characters are passed through this solution, they're converted correctly

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this answers your question, but I'd focus my attention elsewhere.
Namely why the word "Dècor" becomes, if I understood correctly, when loaded in your BigQuery table "DÃ©cor".

Let's say you have a CSV file with the following content:

```
Dècor|Dècor|Dècor
Dècor|Dècor|Dècor
```

If you load it in BigQuery with encoding "ISO-8859-1" it gets corrupted.

```
bq load --autodetect --source_format=CSV  -field_delimiter="|"  -encoding='ISO-8859-1' mydataset.test_french gs://my-bucket/broken_french.csv
```

And here's how the table inside BigQuery looks like:

```
Row string_field_0  string_field_1  string_field_2  
1    DÃ¨cor          DÃ¨cor          DÃ¨cor
2    DÃ¨cor          DÃ¨cor          DÃ¨cor
```

On the other hand, if you use 'UTF-8' encoding, like so:

```
bq load --autodetect --source_format=CSV  -field_delimiter="|"  -encoding='UTF-8' mydataset.test_french2 gs://my-bucket/broken_french.csv
```

the result in BigQuery looks as it should:

```
Row string_field_0  string_field_1  string_field_2  
1    Dècor            Dècor           Dècor
2    Dècor            Dècor           Dècor
```

So, in the case where you're using the wrong encoding to load your data, I'd reload them by using the correct one.